# Why is moment.js allowing date with one digit year when using strict parsing?

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, momentjs, validating

I am using moment.js to parse a date. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

This is to validate and convert the date to a format required by my database. In my testing I encountered this input date '6-4-3' which should not be valid with the given format.

```
moment('6-4-3','YYYY-MM-DD',true).isValid(); //returns true
```

The resulting date in the moment object is "Mon Apr 03 0006 ...". When I call isValid, it returns true. I think it should consider this date invalid because it has too few digits in the input for each part of the format string.

I added a regex.test in my code to ensure that the dates have the right number of digits, but I think this should be handled differently in moment.js when strict is true.

Is there something I'm missing here? Isn't this the point of strict parsing? Or is there a reason why this is the intended behavior?

Comment: Could not reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/0vwmL12u/ -- what version of moment.js are you using?

Comment: Using version version 2.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a known issue for past versions of Moment.js: [YYYY-MM-DD with 3 digit year returns true for isValid()](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1363).

It was fixed in December 2013, and your code works as expected with the most recent version of the library. Version 2.3.1 [was released in October 2013](https://github.com/moment/moment/releases/tag/2.3.1) and does not include this fix.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That makes more sense. I'm not the guy who manages versions of external libraries on this project, so I'll have to see him about that.